# android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: java, android, exception, token, android-windowmanager

I have researched this error on StackOverflow and tried all the suggestions but still have the error. App tries to load and I can see the home screen behind several of the alerts and an error that the app closed.

Things I've tried:

1. adding to Manifest -
2. in `MainActivity`, ensuring I'm using "`this`" in lieu of other references
3. adding to `AlertDialog` -

   `dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`

NOTE: I've also commented out out everything from the `onCreate()` in `MainActivity` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and still have the error. I suspect the issue is directly related to how I'm using my fragment and the tjerk. `ActionSlideExpandableListView` menu.

My code:
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DataPasser {
    private final String LOGCAT = "MAINACTIVITY.LOGCAT";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    Menu menuMain;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    // --------------------------------------------------
    private final String PREF_NAME = "band_wit";
    String firstLaunch = "firstLaunch", itemPosition = "2";

    private TCPdump tcpdump = null;
    private TCPdumpHandler tcpDumpHandler = null;
    static public String local_Ip_Address;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private MyReceiver receiver;

    private static final int VPN_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0F;
    private boolean waitingForVPNStart;

    public static String APP_UID;
    public static String NETFLIX_APP_UID;
    public static String FACEBOOK_APP_UID;

    private BroadcastReceiver vpnStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (LocalVPNService.BROADCAST_VPN_STATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra("running", false))
                    waitingForVPNStart = false;

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        dbHelper = DBHelper.newInstance(this);
        local_Ip_Address = getLocalIpAddress();

        // Local VPN
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                vpnStateReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocalVPNService.BROADCAST_VPN_STATE));

        // ====

         Intent tcp_Dump_Inent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TcpDumpService.class);
         startService(tcp_Dump_Inent);
        /* start service for download manager */
         startService(new Intent(this, MyDownloaderMangerService.class));

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // ** setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(this,
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                //R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name)

        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        // Run when application first time launched
        Const.preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isFirstTime = Const.preferences.getBoolean(firstLaunch, true);
        if (isFirstTime) {
            Const.preferences.edit().putBoolean(firstLaunch, false).commit();
            addBgData(Const.preferences);
            setInitialDataBucket();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash_screen, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            dialog.show();

        }

        APP_UID = myAppUid("com.oda.bandwit");
        NETFLIX_APP_UID = myAppUid("com.netflix.mediaclient");
        FACEBOOK_APP_UID = myAppUid("com.facebook.katana");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();
        try {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            receiver = new MyReceiver();
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        startVPN();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        int fragment = 0;
        Fragment f = this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.frame_container);
        if (f instanceof HomeFragment) {
            fragment = 0;
        } else if (f instanceof GeneralSettingsFragment) {
            fragment = 1;
        } else if (f instanceof ApplicationSettinsFragment) {
            fragment = 2;
        } else if (f instanceof NetworkSettingsFragment) {
            fragment = 3;
        } else if (f instanceof GraphAnalysisFragment) {
            fragment = 4;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuToday:
            menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuSelectedItem).setTitle("Today");
            itemPosition = "0";
            displayView(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuThisWeek:
            menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuSelectedItem).setTitle("Current Week");
            itemPosition = "1";
            displayView(fragment);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuThisMonth:
            menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuSelectedItem).setTitle("Current Month");
            itemPosition = "2";
            displayView(fragment);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menuMain = menu;
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuToday).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuThisWeek).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menuMain.findItem(R.id.menuThisMonth).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menuMain.getItem(Integer.parseInt(itemPosition)).setChecked(true);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menuMain);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */


    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            try {
                fragment = new HomeFragment("" + itemPosition);
                callFragment(position);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ApplicationSettinsFragment();
            callFragment(position);

            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GraphicalAnalysis.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            sendMail();

            break;
        case 4:
            dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Change Limit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Set Threshold");
            ListView list=new ListView(MainActivity.this);
            ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    new String[]{"5","10","15","20","25","30","35","40","45","50","55","60","65","70","75","80","85","90","95","100","105","110","115","120","125","130","135","140","145","150","155","160","165","170","175","180","185","190","195","200"});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Now Threshold " + (position + 1) * 5 +" is set",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    LocalVPNService.netFlixMaxVal = (position + 1) * 5;
                    navDrawerItems.get(4).setCount(""+LocalVPNService.netFlixMaxVal);
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.setView(list);

            dialog=builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            callFragment(position);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
    Dialog dialog;          


    private void callFragment(int position) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == VPN_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            startService(new Intent(this, LocalVPNService.class));

        }
    }
}
```

**Home Fragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Boolean checked;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    String filterFlag = "", networkTypeSelected = "";
    CustomAdapter adap = null;
    OnClickListener clickListener;
    TextView tvNetworkType;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private static String FILENAME = "mlogs.txt";

    public HomeFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public HomeFragment(String dataFilter) {
        filterFlag = dataFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,
                container, false);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());



        try {

            dbHelper = DBHelper.newInstance(getActivity());
            tvNetworkType = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvNetworkTypeHome);
            clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnCellularHome) {
                        checked = false;
                        tvNetworkType.setText("Cellular Data");
                        edit.putString("network", "0");
                    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnWifiHome) {
                        checked = true;
                        tvNetworkType.setText("Wi-fi Data");
                        edit.putString("network", "1");
                    }
                    edit.commit();
                    setListViewData(rootView);

                }

            };

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCellularHome).setOnClickListener(
                    clickListener);
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnWifiHome).setOnClickListener(
                    clickListener);
            if (prefs.getString("network", "0").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                checked = true;
                tvNetworkType.setText("Wi-fi Data");
            } else {
                tvNetworkType.setText("Cellular Data");
                checked = false;
            }

            setListViewData(rootView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        TextView ytdata = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ytdata);
        TcpDumpUtills tcpDumpUtills = new TcpDumpUtills(getActivity());
        ytdata.setText(StringUtils.formatToMultiplier(tcpDumpUtills
                .getAppsConsumedData("com.google.android.youtube")));

        ytdata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");
                      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                      StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
                      String line;
                      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        log.append(line);
                      }

                      writeDataToFile(log.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
            }
        });
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        //mContext = activity;
    }

    public void  writeDataToFile(String data){
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
                try {
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append(data);
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }
    private void writeToFile(String data) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Logss", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        } 

    }
    public ListAdapter getData() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        ArrayList<ListModel> arr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        ArrayList<ListModel> arrFinal = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        String networkType = "";

        if (checked) {
            networkType = "1";
        } else {
            networkType = "0";
        }

        PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        arr = dbHelper.getAppsDataAccordingToNetworkType(networkType);

        if (arr.size() >= 1) {
            for (ListModel modelGetter : arr) {
                ListModel modelSetter = new ListModel();
                String packageName = modelGetter.getAppName();

                // Setting App Name
                try {
                    ApplicationInfo appInfo = manager.getApplicationInfo(
                            modelGetter.getAppName(), 0);
                    String appName = "" + manager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
                    modelSetter.setAppName(appName);

                    // Setting Total Data Consumned by the app
                    long appTotalData = getTotalDataPerApp(modelGetter
                            .getAppName());
                    modelSetter.setDataConsumed(appTotalData);
                    String appTotalDataStr = CommonFunctions
                            .humanReadableByteCount(appTotalData, false);
                    modelSetter.setTotalData(appTotalDataStr);

                    // Setting Total Data as per the network selected
                    long networkDataPerApp = getDailyNetworkDataPerApp(
                            modelGetter.getNetworkData(), packageName);
                    String networkDataStr = CommonFunctions
                            .humanReadableByteCount(networkDataPerApp, false);
                    modelSetter.setNetworkData(networkDataStr);

                    double percd = networkDataPerApp / (double) appTotalData
                            * 100;
                    int perc = (int) percd;
                    modelSetter.setPercenatge(perc);

                    // Setting App Icon
                    Drawable draw = manager.getApplicationIcon(modelGetter
                            .getAppName());
                    modelSetter.setDrawable(draw);

                    // Setting Today's Data
                    long appTodaysData = getUsageData(packageName);
                    String appTodayDataStr = CommonFunctions
                            .humanReadableByteCount(appTodaysData, false);
                    modelSetter.setTodaysData(appTodayDataStr);

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    long dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    long dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    long time = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    long appConsumptionRate = getConsumptionRate(cal,
                            appTotalData);
                    String appConsumptionDataStr = CommonFunctions
                            .humanReadableByteCount(appConsumptionRate, false);
                    if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        appConsumptionDataStr = appConsumptionDataStr + " /hr";
                    } else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        appConsumptionDataStr = appConsumptionDataStr + " /day";
                    }else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                        appConsumptionDataStr = appConsumptionDataStr + " /day.";
                    }
                    modelSetter.setConsumptionRate(appConsumptionDataStr);

                    // Setting Forecast Data
                    long appForecastData = getForecastData(appConsumptionRate,
                            dayOfMonth, dayOfWeek, time, appTotalData);
                    String appForecastDataStr = CommonFunctions
                            .humanReadableByteCount(appForecastData, false);
                    modelSetter.setForecastData(appForecastDataStr);

                    arrFinal.add(modelSetter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }

        } else {
            ListModel modelSetter = new ListModel();
            modelSetter.setAppName("No Data");
            modelSetter.setConsumptionRate("0.0 KB");
            modelSetter.setForecastData("0.0 KB");
            modelSetter.setNetworkData("0.0 KB");
            modelSetter.setTodaysData("0.0 KB");
            modelSetter.setTotalData("0.0 KB");
            arrFinal.add(modelSetter);
        }
        Collections.sort(arrFinal, new Comparator<ListModel>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ListModel lhs, ListModel rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return lhs.getDataConsumed() > rhs.getDataConsumed() ? -1
                         : lhs.getDataConsumed() < rhs.getDataConsumed() ? 1
                         : 0;
            }
        });
        adap = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), arrFinal, res, networkType);
        adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return adap;

    }

    public void setListViewData(View view) {

        try {
            ListAdapter adap = getData();

            ActionSlideExpandableListView list = (ActionSlideExpandableListView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adap);
            list.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

            // listen for events in the two buttons for every list item.
            // the 'position' var will tell which list item is clicked

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    private long getTotalDataPerApp(String packageName) {

        String[] arr = CommonFunctions.getDateAccordingToDuration(filterFlag);

        String sDate = arr[0];
        String eDate = arr[1];
        long data = dbHelper.getDailyTotalDataPerApp(sDate, eDate, packageName);
        return data;
    }

    private long getDailyNetworkDataPerApp(String networkType,
            String packageName) {

        String[] arr = CommonFunctions.getDateAccordingToDuration(filterFlag);

        String sDate = arr[0];
        String eDate = arr[1];
        long data = dbHelper.getDailyNetworkDataPerApp(sDate, eDate,
                networkType, packageName);
        return data;
    }

    private long getUsageData(String packageName) {
        String[] arr = CommonFunctions.getDateAccordingToDuration(filterFlag);

        String sDate = arr[0];
        String eDate = arr[1];

        long data = dbHelper.getDailyTotalDataPerApp(sDate, eDate, packageName);
        return data;
    }

    private long getForecastData(long cRate, long dayOfMonth, long dayOfWeek,
            long time, long appTotalData) {
        long output = 0;
        if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            output = (cRate * (24 - time)) + appTotalData;
        } else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            long leftDaysOfWeek = 7 - dayOfWeek;
            output = (cRate * leftDaysOfWeek) + appTotalData;
        } else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            long leftDaysOfMonth = 31 - dayOfMonth;
            output = (cRate * leftDaysOfMonth) + appTotalData;
        }

        return output;
    }

    private long getConsumptionRate(Calendar cal, long totalData) {
        long output = 0;
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int time = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            output = totalData / time;
        } else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            output = totalData / dayOfWeek;
        } else if (filterFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            output = totalData / dayOfMonth;
        }

        return output;
    }

    public ListAdapter buildDummyData() {
        final int SIZE = 20;
        String[] values = new String[SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            values[i] = "Item " + i;
        }
        return new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.expandable_list_item, R.id.tvAppName, values);
    }

}
```

**Crash Log**
11-19 21:33:24.010 12557-12557/com.oda.bandwit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.oda.bandwit, PID: 12557
                                                                 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:682)
                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
                                                                     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
                                                                     at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService.startTCPdump(TcpDumpService.java:98)
                                                                     at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService.access$000(TcpDumpService.java:22)
                                                                     at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService$1.run(TcpDumpService.java:62)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: add your crash log

Comment: Sorry, here is the crash log.

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.679 6790-6790/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-19 21:02:07.680 6790-6790/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
11-19 21:02:07.744 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.oda.bandwit-1/lib/x86_64
11-19 21:02:07.751 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit V/MAINACTIVITY.LOGCAT: onCreate() called
11-19 21:02:07.814 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit V/MAINACTIVITY.LOGCAT: startService() called

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.868 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.youtube
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:345)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:327)

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at com.oda.bandwitsessions.utility.TcpDumpUtills.getAppsConsumedData(TcpDumpUtills.java:270)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at com.oda.bandwit.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:120)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2352)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
11-19 21:02:07.869 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
11-19 21:02:07.898 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
11-19 21:02:07.933 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit I/LocalVPNService: Started
11-19 21:02:07.935 6790-6850/com.oda.bandwit I/VPNRunnable: Started

Comment: 11-19 21:02:07.937 6790-6846/com.oda.bandwit I/UDPInput: Started
11-19 21:02:07.937 6790-6848/com.oda.bandwit D/TCPInput: Started
11-19 21:02:07.937 6790-6849/com.oda.bandwit I/TCPOutput: Started
11-19 21:02:07.938 6790-6847/com.oda.bandwit I/UDPOutput: Started
11-19 21:02:08.010 6790-6838/com.oda.bandwit I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-19 21:02:08.012 6790-6838/com.oda.bandwit D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-19 21:02:08.983 6790-6790/com.oda.bandwit D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: 11-19 21:07:24.877 11432-11432/com.oda.bandwit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.oda.bandwit, PID: 11432
                                                                 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:682)
                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)

Comment: at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)                                                                    at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService.startTCPdump(TcpDumpService.java:98)
                                                                     at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService.access$000(TcpDumpService.java:22)
                                                                     at com.oda.bandwit.TcpDumpService$1.run(TcpDumpService.java:62)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: I had to break down the crash log into multiple comments due to the limitation of characters. Thank you for your help.

Comment: never add crash log in comment, always add it with your question.

Comment: There's no room to add in question. I didn't want to leave out any of the code. Would you prefer I remove some of the referenced code and replace with the crash log?

Comment: I removed the layout file code references and entered the main section of the crash log. Couldn't enter all of that either (not enough space allowed in comments). Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you have any other input regarding the error message? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.